# ultra diffuse galaxies and dark matter

Tags: observational-astronomy, galaxy, dark-matter, galaxy-cluster

There are ultra diffuse galaxies (UDGs) like, NGC 1052-DF2, NGC 1052-DF4, which seem to have very little dark matter. And on the other hand UDG dragongly 44 has lots of it.
How many UDGs are known to be out there, and what is the dark matter content of these UDGs?